# Physical Position Sensors

Tags: pi-3, sensor

I want to make a RPi-based autopilot for a sailboat, pulling in position, bearing, and speed information against a plotted course and adjusting a rudder accordingly.

I'm pretty comfortable with the development effort necessary, and I can fire off some relays to power some motor that would be attached to the wheel of the boat.

It seems to me, though, that I'll need a way to determine the physical angle the rudder is at, and I can't seem to find any solutions on how to do that.  Googling "position sensor" comes back with a bunch of ultrasound stuff that simply wouldn't be effective in this case.

Is there a specific term I should be looking for?  Or should I be considering an alternate approach?

Comment: Have you considered a stepper motor with feedback.

Comment: I have never heard the term before.  I'm a developer by trade, so I'm a bit weak on the physical implementations.  I'll take a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to circumvent the problem by knowing where you have placed the rudder.

There are two "obvious" solutions.

1. use a stepper motor to position the rudder
2. use a servo motor to position the motor

A stepper motor has a certain number of steps for a complete revolution, say 1000.  To turn a rudder 90 degrees you'd command that stepper to move 250 steps.

A servo motor is told an angle and moves to that angle (the servo is told the angle indirectly by receiving pulses of a certain width, 1ms pulses might be angle -45 and 2ms pulses might be angle +45).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Sounds like the stepper motor is probably closer to what I want.  I'll have to look into it.

Comment: Having done a fair bit of sailing, if this is a keel boat or anything over 16' I think you will want some kind of secondary lock/release mechanism on whatever it is attaches to the wheel or tiller, in addition to the stepper motor -- you could check into what conventional autopilots use (which are pretty sturdy and run off 12V).

Comment: @goldilocks Indeed.  For some reason I assumed the question was about an autonomous model sailing boat (possibly because I've seen that question before).  The torques involved in a real boat are likely to be massive so a servo would appear to be a non-starter.  A stepper would probably need to drive the rudder through additional gearing and even so is likely to slip in heavy seas.

Comment: Just to clarify what I meant by "lock/release" -- autopilots usually use a big steel linear actuator either attached directly to the tiller, or to a special gear on the wheel if the boat has one, and I have a hunch this actuator is locked in place except when the autopilot needs to move it, and friction is used when it isn't so locked (so it can potentially slip and avoid wrenching the motor too much).